# Game where there are N towers of stones and 2 players

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, game-theory

I was wondering whether there's an easy way of seeing the pattern here. I've been thinking about this for hours and haven't been able to formulate it completely.

How the game works is there are 2 players, `N` towers of stones, when it's a player's turn he must remove at least 1 stone from a tower, and the player who removes the last stone(s) wins.

Here's what I've drawn out so far, as a map of the height of the towers to who wins:

```
// {1} ---> "First" (remove the single stone)
// {2} ---> "First" (remove both stones)
// {n}, n > 2 ---> "First" (remove all the stones)
// {1, 1} ---> "Second" (because your only option is to remove 1 stone and then your opponent only has to remove 1 stone to win)
// {1, 2} ---> "First" (because you can remove 1 stone from the 2nd tower and then your opponent is left with {1, 1} which makes him lose as I explained in the last one)
// {1, 3} ---> "First"
// {1, n}, n > 1 ---> "First"
// {2, 2} ---> "Second"
// {2, 3} ---> "First"
// {2, 4} ---> "First"
// {2, n}, n > 2 ---> "First"
// {m, n} ---> m < n ---> "First"
// {1, 1, 1} ---> "First"
// {1, 1, 2} ---> "First"
// {1, 1, 3} ---> "First"
// {1, 1, n} ---> "First"
// {1, 2, 2} ---> "First"
// {1, 2, 3} ---> "Second"
// {1, 2, 4} ---> "First"
// {1, 2, 5} ---> "First"
// {1, 2, n}, n > 3 ---> "First"
// {2, 2, 2} ---> "First"
// {2, 2, 3} ---> "First"
// {2, 2, n}, n > 1 ---> "First"
```

Facts I've come up with:

- If each tower has 1 stone, the player whose turn it is wins if there is an odd number of towers and loses otherwise
- If the number of towers is `N` and the height of any tower is greater than `N+1`, the outcome is the same as if the height of that tower is `N+1`

Either than that, I can't figure out enough of a pattern to write a linear solution.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This game is known as NIM. The winning strategy is to leave a position behind where the XOR of the number of stones in each tower is 0. This forces the opponent to go to a configuration with a non-zero XOR value. The first player can then in turn reach again a position with an XOR value of 0.

For example starting from {1,2,4} a winning move is to go to {1,2,3}. Note that 1 XOR 2 XOR 3 = 0. Lets say the opponent takes 2 stones from the last pile {1,2,1} the next winning move would remove the second pile completely: {1, 0, 1} again making the XOR value 0; and so on.

Comment: Just curious ... Would anyone really be expected to figure that out on their own? Or this just a known trick-problem?

Comment: Somebody must have figured it out in the first place. You may read some more about the theory here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem